# How to make Webview with url file directory in android apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, aide

I want to make my website in html file to android apk.
I was make an app with webview and the url is in file directory, and i found error file not found.
But i don't know to make offline. I am use aide.

Comment: send the screenshot of your error

Comment: //go on this link        https://www.javatpoint.com/android-webview-example

Comment: better to wrap it in cordova

Answer (score 0):

```
 // use this on main activity.
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  
        // mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.javatpoint.com/");  

        /*String data = "<html><body><h1>Hello, Javatpoint!</h1></body></html>"; 
        mywebview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8"); */  

        mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myresource.html");  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But it not work in aide.